# Blazor server performance issues

Tags: performance, blazor, blazor-server-side

Its a Blazor server project with about 100 .razor pages,
When a change occurs on one of the pages, it takes about **19** seconds to rebuild pages, restart *IIS Express* and refresh the page. It's awful, I make only a minor change in html, but it takes long time to show the results.
The test result is like this :

With 100 razor pages and all css and js references 
build : **10** sec 
refresh page : **19** sec (include 10 secs for build)

When we remove 90 pages of 100 pages (10 pages remains) : 
build : **3** sec 
refresh page : **12** sec (include 3 secs for build)

When we remove all css and js references : 
build : **3** sec 
refresh page : **6** sec (include 3 secs for build)

It is not good at all, because the project is growing and finally we will have about 400 pages! and extra css and js references will added. In this case, the time will be much longer for developing.

[image]

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/29416

what's the solution?

*I try to publish the results of my research, it may be useful for others*

**Solution 1:**
OnInitialized calls twice, using OnAfterRender(bool first) {if(firs) {... }} instead of OnInitialized() reduces the time. but does not affect the build time.

**Solution 2:**
Google Chrome browser has the best caching mechanism to reduce the UI render time for test and develope. but does not affect the build time.

**Solution 3:**
I added  disable to my Project inside PropertyGroup tag. It reduced the build time.

Comment: It sounds strange that all pages should be rebuild when you change only one. Check your dependencies?

Comment: I think Blazor rebuilds the whole project after each changes, because it generates everything inside .dll file

Comment: Yes, I did. What happens if I have a 400 page project?

Comment: The loading time of the pages does not depend much on css files.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/29416

Comment: You haven't said how you are building after a change. Are these 100 razor files all in one project? Have you considered splitting them out into smaller class libraries?

Answer (score 1):

I had some of the same problem and I did that:
Can you check your pipelines of startup page,If you use some custom middlewares, try to put them down of `app.UseStaticFiles();` in this case you will be sure that your installed libraries will not be validated by your custom middlewares.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not make a significant difference,

Comment: In microsoft page they said:

"Blazor Server apps that prerender their content call OnInitializedAsync twice:
Once when the component is initially rendered statically as part of the page.
A second time when the browser establishes a connection back to the server.
To prevent developer code in OnInitializedAsync from running twice, see the Stateful reconnection after prerendering section."

So maybe this id a good point to check this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0#stateful-reconnection-after-prerendering

Comment: This solution suggests using OnAfterRender(bool first) instead on OnInitialized(), It's true and it reduce the time a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I am now just seeing this, but I figured it would still help in this case.  I have been using Blazor since 2019 when the code change almost every week.  I had tasked myself to evaluate Blazor Server side vs Client side.  I ran into this same issue with Performance on Server side.  OnAfterRender(bool first) turned out not to be the preferred approach, so I turned to local bool firstLoad value that I checked in OnInitializedAsync to eliminate my issues.  I haven't had the opportunity to evaluate differences between OnAfterRender and OnInitializedAsync as far as which is better.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

We just discovered that Web Sockets had not been installed on the Server that was hosting our Blazor Server application. Installing/enabling web sockets created dramatic improvements in both response time and server requests.